# Execute lambda function for a dataframe set

Tags: python, numpy, dataframe

I've search stackoverflow a bit, and I didn't found a solution, which could be cause by the fact that dataframes are still not very clear to me. I'm doing an exercise which calculates bollinger bands. I've done it for a single stock, but I want to make it work for any number of items. Currently I have this:

```
def movingAverage(symbols, dt_start, dt_end, lookback):
    // Symbols = ['AAPL', 'GOOG']

    ldt_timestamps = du.getNYSEdays(dt_start, dt_end, DT_TIME_OF_DAY)

    c_dataobj = da.DataAccess('Yahoo')
    ls_keys = ['close']

    ldf_data = c_dataobj.get_data(ldt_timestamps, symbols, ls_keys)
    d_data = dict(zip(ls_keys, ldf_data))

    closeData = d_data['close']

    d_data['ma'] = d_data['close'].copy() // calculates the Moving Average for ALL stocks
    d_data['std'] = d_data['close'].copy()
    d_data['bollinger'] = d_data['close'].copy()

    d_data['ma'] = pandas.rolling_mean(d_data['close'], lookback, min_periods=lookback)
    d_data['std'] = pandas.rolling_std(d_data['close'], lookback, min_periods=lookback)
```

I was proud of calculating the `ma` (moving average) and the `std` (rolling standard deviation) for the whole frame instead of doing a loop over the symbols, so what I want to do know is (pseudo-code):

```
for all the symbols
    fill in d_data['bollinger'] with
      (d_data['close'] - d_data['ma']) / d_data['std']
```

I just think I can do this without doing a for loop into each symbol and calculating this by indexing `close` and `data` by symbol index.

Please let me know if the question can be improved.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple as I've described on the pseudo-code:

```
d_data['bollinger'] = (d_data['close'] - d_data['ma']) / d_data['std']
```

Thank to everyone that looked at the topic, next time I'll take some more time to investigate.